# How to detect the change when my google sheet is updated and send an Email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to send an email when my sheet gets new values, The sheet is getting values automatically, and email needs to be sent to a specific Email address, and it needs to be sent to every new entry, so google integrated "Notify on change is out of the question".

Here is my scenario:

1. my source sheet: "Leads"// name of the sheet
2. my target sheet: "Closer"//name of  the sheet

when a new row is inserted into the **Leads sheet** Its values automatically get inserted into the **Closer** sheet in the end. So for each new values inserted in the **Leads**, **Closer** gets a new row.

I have designed a script of my own for that but it sends me too many emails, what I want my script to do is when a new row is inserted send the email, whether that is to self or any email, I know how to send email I am just getting a lot of problems, with getting the change functionality in my script.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Leads");
  var mycell = sheet.getRange("A:A");
  var cellcol = mycell.getColumn();
  var cellrow = mycell.getRow();
  var recipients = "someone@gmail.com";
  var subject = "Notification for sheet updation "+ss.getName();
  var body = ss.getName() + "has been updated.  Visit " + ss.getUrl() + " to view the changes.";
if (mycell == 1)
  {
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }}
```

This function works, but it sends 5,6 emails for each row submitted, I have tried many things but I cannot figure out what is the problem with this code.**I just want my code to send one email for each row inserted**, I would really appreciate some help with this script, Thank you.

Comment: The sheet is getting values automatically means some script updates it. You need to trigger that script.

Comment: So, if you're `sendNotification()` is being triggered 5-6 times per insert you'll need to work out why _that's_ happening.